# I have a txt file. How can I take dictionary key values and print the line of text they appear in?

Tags: python

I have a txt file.  I have written code that finds the unique words and the number of times each word appears in that file.  I now need to figure out how to print the lines that those words apear in as well.  How can I go about doing this?

> Here is a sample output: 
>   Analyze what file: itsy_bitsy_spider.txt
>   Concordance for file itsy_bitsy_spider.txt
>   itsy : Total Count: 2
>   Line:1: The ITSY Bitsy spider crawled up the water spout
>   Line:4: and the ITSY Bitsy spider went up the spout again

```
#this function will get just the unique words without the stop words. 
def openFiles(openFile):

    for i in openFile:
        i = i.strip()
        linelist.append(i)
        b = i.lower()
        thislist = b.split()
        for a in thislist:
            if a in stopwords:
                continue
            else:
                wordlist.append(a)
    #print wordlist




#this dictionary is used to count the number of times each stop 
countdict = {}
def countWords(this_list):
    for word in this_list:
        depunct = word.strip(punctuation)
    if depunct in countdict:
        countdict[depunct] += 1
    else:
        countdict[depunct] = 1
```

Comment: could you show us some sample input and output?

Comment: [here's an implementation that sorts words according to locale](https://gist.github.com/260efcae3b0dfbb05ac7) if `'concordance'` means that the words should be sorted alphabetically on output.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

target = 'itsy'
word_summary = defaultdict(list)
with open('itsy.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    words = [w.strip().lower() for w in line.split()]
    for word in words:
        word_summary[word].append(idx)

unique_words = len(word_summary.keys()) 
target_occurence = len(word_summary[target]) 
line_nums = set(word_summary[target])

print "There are %s unique words." % unique_words 
print "There are %s occurences of '%s'" % (target_occurence, target) 
print "'%s' is found on lines %s" % (target, ', '.join([str(i+1) for i in line_nums]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you parsed the input text file line by line, you could maintain another dictionary that is a word -> List<Line> mapping. ie for each word in a line, you add an entry. Might look something like the following. Bearing in mind I'm not very familiar with python, so there may be syntactic shortcuts I've missed.

eg

```
countdict = {}
linedict = {}
for line in text_file:
    for word in line:
         depunct = word.strip(punctuation)
         if depunct in countdict:
             countdict[depunct] += 1
         else:
             countdict[depunct] = 1

         # add entry for word in the line dict if not there already
         if depunct not in linedict:
             linedict[depunct] = []

         # now add the word -> line entry
         linedict[depunct].append(line)
```

One modification you will probably need to make is to prevent duplicates being added to the linedict if a word appears twice in the line.

The above code assumes that you only want to read the text file once.

Comment: No I have multiple text files that I am reading.  I will add the rest of my code, to give an idea of what I have.  From there, I need to locate my countdict keys in the text file and print the lines that they appear in.

Comment: This will still work for multiple text files, you will just have to call it once for each file, and use the same dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
openFile = open("test.txt", "r")

words = {}

for line in openFile.readlines():
  for word in line.strip().lower().split():
    wordDict = words.setdefault(word, { 'count': 0, 'line': set() })
    wordDict['count'] += 1
    wordDict['line'].add(line)

openFile.close()

print words
```

Comment: You can easily modify this to remove common words from the 'words' dict after.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.  I'm still trying to figure out how I can work it with what I have to get the desired output.

Comment: @SimplyZ: you should not accept this answer yet (in a day or two if it is still the best there is then it's fine to accept it). It doesn't satisfy your question requirements e.g., `stop_words`, line numbers are missing. Compare it to the code I've linked in the comment to your question.

Comment: I accepted it because it led me on the right track and my assignment was due yesterday.  I already had a method for the stop words.  I will however look through the rest of the comments and choose the best method.  Thanks.